# How to save map drawing state (Polygon, Polyline, Markers,Marker)

Tags: javascript, google-maps, google-maps-api-3

i know that this question might be repeated

[How to save map drawing state (Polygon, Polyline, Markers)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10857469/how-to-save-map-drawing-state-polygon-polyline-markers)

but the answer show circle example only , what about other shapes

Polyline for example how to retrieve points store it in array to be used next to display it
I have this code and it work fine

```
   <script>
     function initMap() {
        var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map'), {
            center: { lat: -34.397, lng: 150.644 },
            zoom: 8
        });

        var drawingManager = new google.maps.drawing.DrawingManager({
            drawingMode: google.maps.drawing.OverlayType.MARKER,
            drawingControl: true,
            drawingControlOptions: {
                position: google.maps.ControlPosition.TOP_CENTER,
                drawingModes: ['marker', 'circle', 'polygon', 'polyline', 'rectangle']
            },
            markerOptions: { icon: 'https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/examples/full/images/beachflag.png' },
            circleOptions: {
                fillColor: '#ffff00',
                fillOpacity: 1,
                strokeWeight: 5,
                clickable: false,
                editable: true,
                zIndex: 1
            }
        });
        drawingManager.setMap(map);
        var circles = [];


        google.maps.event.addDomListener(drawingManager, 'circlecomplete', function (circle) {
            circles.push(circle);
        });

        google.maps.event.addDomListener(savebutton, 'click', function () {
            document.getElementById("savedata").value = "";
            for (var i = 0; i < circles.length; i++) {
                var circleCenter = circles[i].getCenter();
                var circleRadius = circles[i].getRadius();
                document.getElementById("savedata").value += "circle((";
                document.getElementById("savedata").value +=
                  circleCenter.lat().toFixed(3) + "," + circleCenter.lng().toFixed(3);
                document.getElementById("savedata").value += "), ";
                document.getElementById("savedata").value += circleRadius.toFixed(3) + ")\n";

            }
        });

    }

    google.maps.event.addDomListener(window, 'load', initialize);

</script>
 <script src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?key=MyKey&libraries=drawing&callback=initMap"
    async defer></script>
```

the Problem is when i try to retrive the coords of a Polyline by adding this part of code :

```
            var Lines = [];
        google.maps.event.addDomListener(drawingManager, 'polylinecomplete', function (polyline) {
            Lines.push(Lines);
        });

        google.maps.event.addDomListener(savebutton, 'click', function () {
            document.getElementById("savedata").value = "";
            for (var i = 0; i < Lines.length; i++) {
                document.getElementById("savedata").value += "Line((";
                document.getElementById("savedata").value +=
                 Lines[i].getPath().getArray().toString();
                document.getElementById("savedata").value += "),";
            }
        });
```

it give me error Line2.aspx:91 Uncaught TypeError: Lines[i].getPath is not a function(…)

Comment: related question: [GMap Drawing tools to image jpeg (static map URL)](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31277220/gmap-drawing-tools-to-image-jpeg-static-map-url)

Answer (score 3):

For retrive the coords of a Polyline

Assuming you have a line like this

```
    var line = new google.maps.Polyline({
      path: linePath,
      geodesic: true,
      strokeColor: '#ff0000',
      strokeOpacity: 1,
      strokeWeight: 4,
      editable: true // if you dont want to see the editable point change it to false
    });
```

You can get the path attribute this way

```
  myPathArray =  line.getPath().getArray()
```

or you can show the content this way

```
  alert(line.getPath().getArray().toString());
```

Then you can inspect myPathArray for get the  lat,lng for each point or send the array to the server for a server side split and store

looking to your code  you should add the new object create this way

```
google.maps.event.addDomListener(drawingManager, 'polylinecomplete', function (polyline) {
        Lines.push(polyline);
});
```

Comment: @BentEl-Eslam    . you add the wrong reference in the array so when try to retrive the object properties you get an error .. i have update my answer   with a suggestion .. hope is useful

Comment: Good heavens!  thank you very much. Now it work fine but there is an exception says  Uncaught ReferenceError: google is not defined(…) it doesn't effect the result but i don't know why it appear