# How to assign unique IDs to drawn GeoJson features and then remove them based on their ID?

Tags: javascript, google-maps-api-3

I'm trying to assign a unique ID to each feature that gets drawn on this [Google Map](http://jsfiddle.net/gmt0vdd0/2/), and then use the `rightclick` event to remove the feature that gets clicked on. Currently all features get removed, which is a problem.

Once the feature is added to the collection, I try to assign the unique ID:

```
var uniqueID = function() {
  return ++currentID;
}
dataLayer.addListener('addfeature', savePolygon, function(event) {
    event.feature.setProperty('featureID', uniqueID);
});
```

Then on `rightclick` event, I want to remove the feature that gets clicked on. I assumed you would need to have unique IDs for this step, hence the prior step.

```
dataLayer.addListener('rightclick', function() {
    dataLayer.forEach(function(feature) {
        dataLayer.remove(feature);
        localStorage.removeItem('geoData');
    });
});
```

Full code below.

**JS:**

```
var map;
var currentID = 0;
var uniqueID = function() {
  return ++currentID;
}

function initMap() {
  map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map'), {
    center: {
      lat: -34.397,
      lng: 150.644
    },
    zoom: 4,
    // only show roadmap type of map, and disable ability to switch to other type
    mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP,
    mapTypeControl: false
  });

  map.data.setControls(['Polygon']);
  map.data.setStyle({
    editable: true,
    draggable: true
  });
  bindDataLayerListeners(map.data);

  //load saved data
  loadPolygons(map);
}


// Apply listeners to refresh the GeoJson display on a given data layer.
function bindDataLayerListeners(dataLayer) {
  dataLayer.addListener('addfeature', savePolygon, function(event) {
    event.feature.setProperty('featureID', uniqueID);
  });

  dataLayer.addListener('rightclick', function() {
    dataLayer.forEach(function(feature) {
      dataLayer.remove(feature);
      localStorage.removeItem('geoData');
    });
  });

  dataLayer.addListener('setgeometry', savePolygon);
}

function loadPolygons(map) {
  var data = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem('geoData'));

  map.data.forEach(function(f) {
    map.data.remove(f);
  });
  map.data.addGeoJson(data)
}



function savePolygon() {
  map.data.toGeoJson(function(json) {
    localStorage.setItem('geoData', JSON.stringify(json));
  });

}
initMap();
```

Original source: I built this example from a JSFiddle found in [this thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10857469/how-to-save-map-drawing-state-polygon-polyline-markers).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

your `addfeature` listener was wrong, as `addListener` takes only a single callback function, so you need to call `e.feature.setProperty` then `savePolygon` inside a single anonymous callback function

Note, you had `event.feature.setProperty('featureID', uniqueID);` - it needs to be `event.feature.setProperty('featureID', uniqueID());`

```
    dataLayer.addListener('addfeature', function(event) {
        event.feature.setProperty('featureID', uniqueID());
        savePolygon(event);
    });
```

Then, in the `rightclick` lsitener, you can simply get the `geoData` - filter out the clicked item, save the `geoData` and then `dataLayer.remove(e.feature);`

```
    dataLayer.addListener('rightclick', function(e) {
        var data = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem('geoData'));
        data.features = data.features.filter(function(feature) {
            return feature.properties.featureID !== e.feature.getProperty('featureID');
        });
        localStorage.setItem('geoData', JSON.stringify(data));
        dataLayer.remove(e.feature);
    });
```

**[working fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/jaromanda/gmt0vdd0/3/)**

Comment: Wow, simple indeed. The only reason I was trying to assign IDs is so I can remove it from localStorage too. `dataLayer.remove(e.feature);` only removes it from the map.

Comment: yes, I noticed that after I posted the answer ... looking at it now

Comment: Updated the answer

Comment: Thanks for your the explanation! Works well.