# How to save map drawing from Javascript to django-sqlite3 without forms

Tags: javascript, django, django-models, dom-events

I read this solution to draw a polygon but can´t figure out how to save this data in my database
[How to save map drawing state (Polygon, Polyline, Markers)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10857469/how-to-save-map-drawing-state-polygon-polyline-markers) the 2nd answer.

I need to draw a polygon and make some math from it, like area. and when the user is login I want to show it.

---

```
function loadPolygons(map) {
    var data = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem('geoData'));

    map.data.forEach(function (f) {
        map.data.remove(f);
    });
    map.data.addGeoJson(data)
}

function savePolygon() {
    map.data.toGeoJson(function (json) {
        localStorage.setItem('geoData', JSON.stringify(json));
    });
```

Comment: If I'm reading that correctly, you're asking how to store an object on the server instead of in localStorage? Which basically means you're looking for [`fetch()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Fetch_API/Using_Fetch)

Comment: Thanks Chirs. yes, instead of in localStorage.  I will try and tell you if can make it! Thanks!!!